# I'm trying to run my Codeigniter Project on my local XAMPP server but I either get connection refused, website not found or not existing domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I have a Codeigniter project that I want to try out on my local XAMPP server. The URL for the Project is "https://maap:8890/" as specified in the config file:

`$config['base_url'] = 'https://maap:8890/';`

The real URL is "http://127.0.0.1/maap/index.php" and I'm using mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file as follows:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I first tried just starting XAMPP and trying the website. The full URL (127.0.0.1/maap/index.php) was succesfully redirected to https://maap:8890/login but that site just displayed DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN so I googled a lot and found out that I maybe have to setup a Virtual Host. So I did as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\maap"
ServerName maap
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\maap">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf and this is my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1           maap
```

Now if I typed in my full URL it just showed a 404 error. If I then tried to reach https://maap:8890/ instead, I get a connection refused error. I tried all of this on Chrome and Edge and I tried changing the port of the virtual host to 443 or 8890 but nothing has helped. The Codeigniter project isn't from me and I know for sure that it works on Mamp on a Mac. I'm sorry if my problem seems dumb or I'm describing the wrong things but I am really new to this stuff. I hope someone can help me or give me any clue as to what else I could try. I'm happy to provide more code if it's needed

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343952/how-to-perfectly-set-up-virtual-host-for-codeigniter-project

Comment: Thank you but I already found that thread and tried it out and it didn't change anything for me. Now that you mentioned it again I even tried deleting the content of my htaccess file and just putting the suggestion from that thread in. If I now try to reach the full URL I'm getting 500 Server Error. When trying to reach maap:8890 I still get connection refused

Comment: I have to ask, why do you think you have https and why do you think it needs to be on that port? I was hoping that the suggested post would get you thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how to get it working with the maap url but I just changed the baseurl to "http://127.0.0.1/maap/" and everything worked fine. So I guess I did not really fix it but found a work around for my problem